# Particles.js into Vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, particles.js

I'm trying to adapt [particles.js](https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) to a Vue.js component from the example below:
https://codepen.io/MichaelVanDenBerg/pen/WpXGRm

However, when using the code below, I get the following error message in the console:

> [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.particles is not a
>   function"

How can I fix it in the code below?

**Template:**

```html
</template>
    <div>
        <div id="particles-js"></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**Script:**

```html
<script>
import particles from 'particles.js'
export default {
    mounted() {
        this.initParticles()
    },
    methods: {
        initParticles () {
            particles("particles-js", {
                "particles": {
                    "number": {
                        "value": 80,
                        "density": {
                            "enable": true,
                            "value_area": 700
                        }
                    },
                    "color": {
                        "value": "#ffffff"
                    },
                    "shape": {
                        "type": "circle",
                        "stroke": {
                            "width": 0,
                            "color": "#000000"
                        },
                        "polygon": {
                            "nb_sides": 5
                        },
                    },
                    "opacity": {
                        "value": 0.5,
                        "random": false,
                        "anim": {
                            "enable": false,
                            "speed": 1,
                            "opacity_min": 0.1,
                            "sync": false
                        }
                    },
                    "size": {
                        "value": 3,
                        "random": true,
                        "anim": {
                            "enable": false,
                            "speed": 40,
                            "size_min": 0.1,
                            "sync": false
                        }
                    },
                    "line_linked": {
                        "enable": true,
                        "distance": 150,
                        "color": "#ffffff",
                        "opacity": 0.4,
                        "width": 1
                    },
                    "move": {
                        "enable": true,
                        "speed": 6,
                        "direction": "none",
                        "random": false,
                        "straight": false,
                        "out_mode": "out",
                        "bounce": false,
                        "attract": {
                            "enable": false,
                            "rotateX": 600,
                            "rotateY": 1200
                        }
                    }
                },
                "interactivity": {
                    "detect_on": "canvas",
                    "events": {
                        "onhover": {
                                "enable": true,
                                "mode": "grab"
                        },
                        "onclick": {
                            "enable": true,
                            "mode": "push"
                        },
                        "resize": true
                    },
                    "modes": {
                        "grab": {
                            "distance": 140,
                            "line_linked": {
                                "opacity": 1
                            }
                        },
                        "bubble": {
                            "distance": 400,
                            "size": 40,
                            "duration": 2,
                            "opacity": 8,
                            "speed": 3
                        },
                        "repulse": {
                            "distance": 200,
                            "duration": 0.4
                        },
                        "push": {
                            "particles_nb": 4
                        },
                        "remove": {
                            "particles_nb": 2
                        }
                    }
                },
                "retina_detect": true
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```html
<style scoped>
#particles-js {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #00356B;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 12):

The [`particles.js` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/particles.js) does not export anything, but rather it [sets `window.particlesJS`](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/blob/677c14c/particles.js#L1477).

To use this package, simply import it in your script, and then invoke `particlesJS()`:

```js
import 'particles.js'
export default {
  // ...
  methods: {
    initParticles() {
      window.particlesJS('particles-js', {/* ... */})
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/718qvn2vk6)

Comment: Really appreciate you going to the effort of the demo, I was approaching this wrong and coming across your comment brought me back on track.